# SQL - Finding the Grand Total of a column where some values are null

Tags: sql

I work for a large construction company and I recently implemented a tool tracking system. I'm in the process of building reports that interface with the software.

Tools are broken into two classifications at their highest level, either binned or individual. Binned items are tools like wrenches, screwdrivers etc and are assigned one barcode for all tools. Individual tools are high value and are assigned an individual barcode (hence the name).

The report I'm building aims to show the prices of all the tools checked out to a particular job along with the grand total. My issue is that the individual items are treated as `NULL` in the checked out column. So when I try to find the total value of the tools I am using `(out_qty * price) AS TotalValue`. But because `out_qty` is `NULL` for individual tools there is no value in the `TotalValue` field, making it hard to sum the grand total.

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I can't quite figure it out.

```
SELECT t.bcode, t.des, t.asset_num, t.model, t.sn, t.bin, t.consumable,
  t.status, t.price, ch.outdte, f.fac, cl.loc, ch.bin_qty,
  h.notes as hist_note, sl.loc as storloc, sf.fac as storfac,
  rtrim(e2.lname) + ', ' + rtrim(e2.fname) + ' - ' + rtrim(e2.bcode) AS empname,
  FORMAT(t.price * h.bin_qty, "Currency") AS TotalValue
FROM ((((((t_tool t inner join t_checkout ch on t.tool_id = ch.tool_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_loc cl on ch.loc_id = cl.loc_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_fac f on cl.fac_id = f.fac_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_loc sl on sl.loc_id = t.storloc_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_fac sf on sf.fac_id = sl.fac_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_emp e2 on cl.emp_id = e2.emp_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_hist h
    on (h.tool_id = ch.tool_id and h.loc_id = ch.loc_id and h.dte = ch.outdte)
WHERE cl_loc.id{*loc_id}

UNION

SELECT t.bcode, t.des, t.asset_num, t.model, t.sn, t.bin, t.consumable,
  t.status, t.price, t.outdte, f.fac, cl.loc, null as bin_qty,
  h.notes as hist_note, sl.loc as storloc, sf.fac as storfac,
  rtrim(e2.lname) + ', ' + rtrim(e2.fname) + ' - ' + rtrim(e2.bcode) as empname,
  FORMAT(t.price * h.bin_qty, "Currency") AS TotalValue
FROM (((((t_tool t left join t_loc cl on t.chkloc_id = cl.loc_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_fac f on cl.fac_id = f.fac_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_loc sl on sl.loc_id = t.storloc_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_fac sf on sf.fac_id = sl.fac_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_emp e2 on cl.emp_id = e2.emp_id) 
  LEFT JOIN t_hist h
    on (h.tool_id = t.tool_id and h.loc_id = t.chkloc_id and h.dte = t.outdte) 
WHERE cl_loc.id{*loc_id}
ORDER BY des
```

Comment: There is usually a function to convert nulls to a particular value in every DBMS. In Oracle, you can use "NVL(COLUMN, DEFAULT VALUE)". See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Check this page: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Why all the nesting of joins? Can't remove all those brackets? I would start there

Comment: What does the expression `cl_loc.id{*loc_id}` mean?  I'm not familiar with that syntax.  Moreover, how is it sensible that it appears to refer to a table or alias `cl_loc` that is not specified in the `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: The cl_loc.id{*loc_id} is the GUID operator which interfaces with the tool tracking system which tells the application to show a location drop down list. I had never seen it previously either, but that's the way the reports have to be written according to the software company.

Comment: Ok.  At least, is `cl_loc.id` supposed to be `cl.loc_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is SQL Server you can use the ISNULL function

So your calculation would be:

```
(ISNULL(out_qty,0) * price) AS TotalValue
```

As mentioned in comments, Oracle uses NVL...

```
(NVL(out_qty,0) * price) AS TotalValue
```

The 0 (zero) default value means you want to use Zero when the out_qty is NULL

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something like that, just a matter of getting the syntax.